# How to get the content of a DOM from a HTML loaded in an Android webview?

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, html

for example:
the webpage **loaded in an webview** is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $.get(
    '/my.url',
    function(data){
        $('#e').html(data);
    }
    );
}
);
</script>
<div id='e'></div>
```

How can I get the content of the DOM id 'e' from the Java codes or get the content during the 'get' call back?

the java part
`final WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);`

how can I make use of `browser` to extract the content in the webview?

Comment: I'm confused about what you need specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have founded out is to have the JS send the value to your device through the JS interface. Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) about this.

Then you have two options, either you call the interface from the $(document).ready callback or you use the webView.loadUrl("javascript:XXXX") to call a JS function that will get the value in the DOM and pass it to your interface.

In my project, I need to get some values from the webpage when it is loaded. I've develop a WebAppInfoLoader that call a JS function that return the value of the asked variable :

```
mWebView.loadUrl(String.format("javascript:sendValueToDeviceInterface(%s);", jsValue.getId()));
```

Then, the JS function call the interface which notify the loader that the value has been received. When the loader has gather all values, he himself notify the calling object.

It's quite sophisticated and very unfortunate that Google hasn't come up with a more simple system as it exist on iOS.